# How can I execute a command when a buffer is closed in vim?

Tags: vim, vi

Is there something like a close-window-hook in vim/vimscript, so that I can call a function every time a window is closed?

I want to use it for the following scenario:
I use an extra scratch window to display information about the file, and when I close the file I want the scratch window to be closed automatically so that vim exits.

If you have any ideas how to achieve that without a hook that will be just as fine.

edit:
I know about `:qa[ll]`, but I am lazy and only want to type `:q` or `ZZ`.

edit2.71828183:
I accepted the autocommand answer as it was closest to the original question, but found another solution in using a preview window instead of a split window. A preview window is automatically closed when the last "normal" window is closed..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

autocommands are amazing! I'm pretty sure that in this case, `BufLeave` will do the job, but you might want `BufWinLeave`? Have a look at `:help autocmd-events` for a full list of events.

The other bit you'll care about is: you can have buffer-local autocommands! (`:help autocmd-buflocal`)

You can define one for the current buffer using `au BufLeave <buffer> ...`. My best guess is that you could run this in whatever command creates the scratch window. You should be able to cache the scratch window's buffer number in a global variable when you open the scratch window, then your autocommand could just delete that buffer (`:help :bdelete`).

```
au BufLeave <buffer> bdelete g:scratch_buffer
call CreateScratchWindow()

function CreateScratchWindow() {
    ...
    let g:scratch_buffer = bufnr("")
}
```

There's also a function winbufnr, for getting buffer numbers by window. You can use either one - just make sure that the scratch window/buffer is current when you use it! (The "" means current window/buffer).

Comment: Autocommands are what I was looking for when asking for a hook, thanks for the tip.
But I can't make this autocommand work to solve my original problem. It closes the scratch buffer, but then the original file does not close!

Comment: I think you want `BufUnload` instead.

Comment: @rampion: I believe that when a window is closed, the buffer it contained becomes hidden, which should not trigger `BufUnload`. Have you actually tried it?

@0x89: That's very strange. The autocommand shouldn't be able to affect execution outside of itself. A kludge to get it to work might be to have the autocommand close the original file too. (use | to concatenate commands, or write a function for the autocommand to call)

Comment: If the buffer is hidden or unloaded depends on the `hidden` setting, as well as on the `bufhidden` option. Maybe that is the solution: I have "set hidden" in my `.vimrc`, so when I close the first buffer, it becomes _hidden_, then the autocommand closes the other one, which makes the first window visible again - tricky! So I could close the window in the au. But I found another solution: I use a preview window instead of a split window (see :help preview). That is automatically closed when there are no other windows left..

Comment: Oh!  I'm sorry, I meant to suggest that in the first place, but got totally distracted by buffer-local autocommands.

Answer (score 0):

Add a mapping.

```
:nnoremap :q :qa
```

then, if you only want to use `:q` one day, you can just

```
:qa<backspace>
```

and normally, you can just

```
:q<enter>
```

and get

```
:qa<enter>
```

for free.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, not really a new question, but I found it looking for, what I now know, `BufWinLeave`. However, the scenario the author is describing is something I have in my `vimrc` with `NerdTree`, e.g. when the last buffer is closed, I want vim to close the `NerdTree` "buffer" and then quit.

```
autocmd bufenter * if (winnr("$") == 1 && exists("b:NERDTree") && b:NERDTree.isTabTree()) | q | endif
```

Replace the `NERDTree` specific stuff with how the `scratch` buffer is identified.

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
:quitall
```

or

```
:qall
```

to close all windows at once.

add a `!` if you want to ignore unsaved changes.

```
:qall!
```

Comment: Sorry, that is not what I want. I want the second window to automatically close, no matter how the first window is closed. That includes ZZ, :q, whatever. Especially I don't want to type :qa all the time, :q is hard-wired into my fingers..